# tcpdump gives encrypted results

Tags: ubuntu, tcpdump

If I run the following: `tcpdump -A -w /tmp/apache_outgoing.pcap` trigger an event and then look at the pcap file I see something like:

`�y�<�*�^L�cM9��^U^MK`

Is there any way to make the tool human readable output?

Comment: How are you looking at the pcap file? It's not meant to be human-readable. Just use tcpdump to read it again. Or use wireshark.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the output via tcpdump -r; e.g. `tcpdump -r /tmp/apache_outgoing.pcap`

Answer (score 0):

The question is : What are you trying to dump ?

Is the traffic encrypted such as HTTPs ?

Maybe you should investigate in this way because it seem to be your problem.

> Note : You can analyse your pcap in Wireshark to get better visual aspect.